# R: Box.test vs adf.test vs kpss.test

Tags: r, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller, kpss-test

I stuck in checking my Time Seies for stationarity with several tests:

```
Box.test(ts, lag = 20, type="Ljung")
adf.test(ts)
kpss.test(ts,null="Trend")
kpss.test(diff(ts),null="Trend")
```

And the output:

```
Box-Ljung test p-value < 2.2e-16
Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test p-value = 0.4301
KPSS Test for Trend Stationarity p-value = 0.01
KPSS Test for Trend Stationarity p-value = 0.1
```

So Box and adf tests tells me what i can accept stationarity of my ts, but kpss tells what ts is not stationary, after it 1st difference in kpss is stationary. How this can be explained?
(i use these tests before i do arima fitting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is not really R-specific (which is good, because I'm not an R expert).

The Ljung-Box test tests the null hypothesis of absence of serial correlation which is much stronger than stationarity. This is rejected here.

The ADF test has the null of a unit root, which is not rejected. So it's just the opposite of "accept stationarity".

The KPSS test has the null of (trend) stationarity, which is rejected here (depending on your significance level) in favor of a unit root. This is compatible with the ADF test result (congratulations, because this is not actually always the case in practice).

The KPSS on the differences accepts the stationarity null, which fits nicely with the other test results, because a unit root in the levels is eliminated after differencing.

So all in all, you seem to have a wonderful example for an integrated (unit root) time series where none of the tests contradict the others.